# confusion ns2 : agents classifiers and nodes

Tags: linux, agent, classification, ns2

Nodes represent the basic structures in ns2. They inherit from TclObject class.

Agents are like TcpAgent and UdpAgent or NullAgent and they inherit from NsObject class, which itself inherits from TclObject. Agent can send data to one target_ to which they are connected. target_ is NsObject *.

Classifiers inherit from NsObject. They can send data to many as they have got the list. NsObject **.

Node Class has neighbour_list. Node has a RoutingModule object which has got the classifier. but since Node is not NsObject type, i can't put Node in the classifier's NsObject**.

I want to implement something (i do not know whether an Agent or a Node or Classifier) (i think it should be a classifier) so that i can get the neighbors of the node and send packets to some depending upon the logic.

What should i do ? if i implement a classifier how do i attach it with node.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered one of my questions. It would help.
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765726/what-can-be-done-in-ns2-and-what-can-not-be)

In a nutshell, in a wireless scenario, to get the neighbors of the nodes,

1. BROADCAST PING messages by ns_addr_t.addr_ = -1.
2. On Receiving PING, store the sender of message as my neighbor. Send PING_REPLY to it.
3. On Receiving PING_REPLY, store the sender of message as my neighbor.

After some time, set simulator to start the protocol.

> $ns at 500.0 "$myagent start-protocol"