# All nodes that are in Range are not receiving Message in LEACH

Tags: ubuntu, ns2

when I send Broadcast notification to other nodes some nodes are not receiving the notification. below is code. Any help is appreciated Thanks

```
int clusterCode;
int numCodesAvail;

numCodesAvail = 2 * config_.spreading_ - 1;


currentCH_ = sensor_node_->nodeid();
currentCHMAC_ = MAC_BROADCAST;

clusterCode = (mac_->myADVnum() % numCodesAvail) + 1;

setCode(clusterCode);

wakeUp();

send(
    MAC_BROADCAST,
    LINK_BROADCAST,
    LEACH_ADV_CH,
    (char *) (&code_),
    sizeof(currentCH_),
    BYTES_ID,
    config_.maxDist_,
    0);

listenJOINREQ_ = true;

clusterNodes_.clear();
```

This works fine in first round but in second some of the nodes are not receiving  the notification.

Comment: can there be something that would make node to reject a message, like some variable. try printing variables through your code.

Comment: you ever worked on LEACH ?

Comment: no i never worked on it.

Comment: can you please give me your few minutes ? I am struggling to find, why all nodes are not receiving  notification. ? it works find in first round but in second round it is not sending notification of all other nodes

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54926/ns-2